# Better solution for dev-enviorment/debugging for google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, aptana

After a few months developing in GAE using google's standalone server (dev_appserver) and Aptana Studio I'm start to get more and more annoyed over my current development environment.

As of now there's a couple of things that bothers me.

1. I don't get any code assistants from my own written methods and classes. **[Solved] One have to add the project dir to the projects python path manually. Go Project -> Properties -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH. Under the tab "Source folders". Click "Add Source Folder". Select the main project folder. "OK". Now you should have code assist across you entire project.**
2. When debugging, the debugger doesn't provides correct watches, current variables, post data and so forth. If I assign for example some POST data to a variable it show's up correctly. But not if I look at the POST data it self.
3. Some how the Aptana debugger server(it start's it own instance of dev_appserver) doesn't seem to have access to the datastore. **[Solved] Found out (of course, stupid of me) you have to set the same flag in to the datastore as in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher to tell the server where to reach the datastore. Go Run -> Debug configurations. Select the configuration you using. Go to the tab "Arguments" and add the datastore flag. --datastore_path=[path to datastore]**
4. Feels kinda dumb to have 2 server running the same application, is there away to make the dev_appserver (I'm running the GoogleAppEngineLauncher) to break on breakpoints in another program?

If anyone has any solution to theses problems, ideas or just a completely different suggestion for development any ideas or fixes are more then welcome!

EDIT: Solved problems 1 and 3. See updated post.

..fredrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely check out PyCharm and its fantastic out of the box Google App Engine support : http://www.basarat.com/2011/06/google-app-engine-python-pycharm-love.html

Comment: I'm currently using it. And it's the best IDE I've found!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the standalone version of Aptana Studio? Because that is more aimed at web development using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I believe the support for Python debugging is fairly limited.

Try using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) plugin which gives you much better Python debugging support. Also, the latest PyDev plugin supports GAE projects.
And you can still use Aptana Studio for your HTML/CSS/JavaScript, because it is available as an Eclipse plugin as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I encountered the same problems here. Except I managed to get the datastore working (same fixed work also in Aptana). But still can't get the debugger and code completion/code assistants to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with getting Aptana or Eclipse working, but I can attest that Wing IDE ($35/personal license) has superb code completion and debugging. I work with it everyday and do a great deal of AppEngine development with it. It just works.

Comment: They have a free trial period, so you can check it out without actually making a purchase.